# Compare two dataframe and assign new date on change

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two df, with some changes in column "C" between df1 and df2. You see in column "D" identical dates in all rows of df1 and df2.
If there is a change in column C now, the date in df2.D shall be updated to today, all others shall remain on 2022-08-01.

With the last command, i get the current date for all differences in C. But how can I remain on the old value for not differing values between C? If I type instead "0" e.g. df2['C'] this doesn't work.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import date

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A": ['Apply','Strawberry','Cherry'],"C":['green','red','red'],"D":['2022-08-01','2022-08-01','2022-08-01']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"A": ['Apply','Strawberry','Cherry'],"C":['red','red','red'],"D":['2022-08-01','2022-08-01','2022-08-01']})

df2['D']=np.where(df1['C']==df2['C'],0,date.today())
```

This means, as result I want the following dataframe:

```
d2 = A": ['Apply','Strawberry','Cherry'],"C":['red','red','red'],"D":[**today**,'2022-08-01','2022-08-01']
```

and not:

```
d2 = A": ['Apply','Strawberry','Cherry'],"C":['red','red','red'],"D":[**today**,0,0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code**

1.use `where`

```
df2.assign(D=df2['D'].where(df1['C']==df2['C'], date.today()))
```

output:

```
    A           C   D
0   Apply       red 2023-10-15    <--today
1   Strawberry  red 2022-08-01
2   Cherry      red 2022-08-01
```

2. If you want to create a column using = inplace, you can use the following code:

```
df2['D'] = df2['D'].where(df1['C']==df2['C'], date.today())
```

same result above

However, it is a good idea to use a method that does not overwrite the original DataFrame(df2) when changing values based on a condition, especially when the code will be run multiple times.

3. If you need to use np.where, use the following code:

```
df2['D'] = np.where(df1['C']==df2['C'], df2['D'], date.today())
```

---

**Example**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import date

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A": ['Apply','Strawberry','Cherry'],"C":['green','red','red'],"D":['2022-08-01','2022-08-01','2022-08-01']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"A": ['Apply','Strawberry','Cherry'],"C":['red','red','red'],"D":['2022-08-01','2022-08-01','2022-08-01']})
```

Answer (score 1):

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import date

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A": ['Apple','Strawberry','Cherry'], "C": ['green', 'red', 'red'], "D": ['2022-08-01', '2022-08-01', '2022-08-01']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"A": ['Apple', 'Strawberry', 'Cherry'], "C": ['red', 'red', 'red'], "D": ['2022-08-01', '2022-08-01', '2022-08-01']})

def update_date(row):
    if row['C'] != df1.loc[df1['A'] == row['A'], 'C'].values[0]:
        return str(date.today())
    return row['D']

df2['D'] = df2.apply(update_date, axis=1)
print(df2)
```

**Output:**

[image]